# How can I git pull in Windows like Mac sudo permission?

Tags: windows, git

In my Macbook I can use the `sudo git pull` to pull the project new change in my other computer.

but how can I in Windows10 to do like this?

Because in the Windows10 I can not use `sudo`, and I also find a related command that is `runas` but I seems can not use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `sudo` on the git bash in Windows.

Just type `git pull <name of remote> <name of branch>` and you're good to go. Make sure you have access to the remote repo you're pulling from.